debugger.SendCommand 'Runtime.evaluate' expression:'window.open' does not work
I want to open a new tab with dynamic code in my chrome-extension(v3).
So I take the api: chrome.debugger.sendCommand('Runtime.evaluate'), it can execute the javascript I expected mostly.But 'window.open' can not make any sense while the 'window.close' can work well.
How cloud i make the code 'window.open' work well with chrome.debugger.sendCommand('Runtime.evaluate')
await chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId: 71418804 }, 'Runtime.evaluate', { expression:"window.open('https://www.baidu.com/')", includeCommandLineAPI:true, executionWorld: "MAIN" });


executionWorld is not listed in the options of this command, 2) window.open may have been spoofed by the site or another extension, so it's more reliable to do it in the content script that runs in the default world (ISOLATED) or use chrome.tabs.create in the extension directly instead of window.open.

